# Trying to migrate from tslint to eslint in angular@13. Getting lots of dependency errors

Tags: angular, eslint, prettier, tslint

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wD2jK.png)

I've tried to run "npm i" after cleaning the cache. but not working. Is there anything i'm missing?
Do i need to update the version of the @angular/cdk or flex-layout?

Comment: "i need to update the version of the @angular/cdk or flex-layout?" yes

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-ot-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) to see how you can improve your question.